# Unable to submit a spark job on spark cluster on docker

Tags: java, scala, docker, apache-spark, hadoop

Like anticipated by the title, I have some problems to submit a spark job to a spark cluster running on docker.

I wrote a very simple spark job in scala, subscribe to a kafka server arrange some data and store these in an elastichsearch database.
kafka and elasticsearch are already running in docker.

**Everything works perfectly if I run the spark job from my Ide in my dev environment (Windows / IntelliJ).**

Then (and I'm not a java guy at all), I added a spark cluster following these instructions: https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-spark

The cluster looks healthy when consulting its dashboard. I created a cluster consisting of a master and a worker.

Now, this is my job written in scala:

```
import java.io.Serializable

import org.apache.commons.codec.StringDecoder
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem
import org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.elasticsearch.spark._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.{ConsumerStrategies, KafkaUtils}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}

import scala.util.parsing.json.JSON

object KafkaConsumer {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val sc = new SparkConf()
      .setMaster("local[*]")
      .setAppName("Elastic Search Indexer App")

    sc.set("es.index.auto.create", "true")

    val elasticResource = "iot/demo"
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(10))

    //ssc.checkpoint("./checkpoint")

    val kafkaParams = Map(
      "bootstrap.servers" -> "kafka:9092",
      "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest",
      "group.id" -> "group0"
    )

    val topics = List("test")
    val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
      ssc,
      PreferConsistent,
      ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String, String](topics.distinct, kafkaParams)
    )

    case class message(key: String, timestamp: Long, payload: Object)
    val rdds = stream.map(record => message(record.key, record.timestamp, record.value))

    val es_config: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String] =
      scala.collection.mutable.Map(
        "pushdown" -> "true",
        "es.nodes" -> "http://docker-host",
        "es.nodes.wan.only" -> "true",
        "es.resource" -> elasticResource,
        "es.ingest.pipeline" -> "iot-test-pipeline"
      )


    rdds.foreachRDD { rdd =>
      rdd.saveToEs(es_config)
      rdd.collect().foreach(println)
    }

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

To submit this to the cluster I did:

- With "sbt-assembly" plugin, I created a fat jar file with all dependencies.
- Define an assembly strategy in build.sbt to avoid deduplicate errors on merging ...

Then submit with:

> ./spark-submit.cmd --class KafkaConsumer --master
>   spark://docker-host:7077
>   /c/Users/shams/Documents/Appunti/iot-demo-app/spark-streaming/target/scala-2.11/
>   spark-streaming-assembly-1.0.jar

BUT I have this error:

> 19/02/27 11:18:12 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop
>   library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where
>   applicable Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: **No
>   FileSystem for scheme: C**
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getHadoopFileSystem(Utils.scala:1897)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:694)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.downloadFile(DependencyUtils.scala:135)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$doPrepareSubmitEnvironment$7.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:416)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$doPrepareSubmitEnvironment$7.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:416)
>           at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doPrepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:415)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:250)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:171)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

**After a day of trying I have not solved and I can not understand where in my work wants to access a certain volume as seems to be said by the error**

Can be related with the warning message?
Then, how I should edit my script to avoid that problem?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Problem seems not related to my code because I tried tu submit a simple hello world app compiled in the same way but I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts and research I have come to the conclusion that the problem could be that I'm using the windows version of spark-submit from my pc to submit the job.

I could not fully understand but for now, moving the file directly to the master and worker node I was able to submit it from there.

First copy on the container:

```
docker cp spark-streaming-assembly-1.0.jar 21b43cb2e698:/spark/bin
```

Then I execute *(in /spark/bin folder)*:

```
./spark-submit --class KafkaConsumer --deploy-mode cluster --master spark://spark-master:7077 spark-streaming-assembly-1.0.jar
```

This is the workaround that i found at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount the directory of your jobs to your container by running your submit container like this

```
docker run -it --rm\
--name spark-submit \
--mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/jobs,target=/home/jobs,readonly \
--network spark-net \
-p 4040:4040 \
-p 18080:18080 \
your-spark-image \
bash
```

This command will mount your jobs folder directly to your container and you can change in host and those changes will automatically be present in your container